# Wait until a javascript function has finished before carrying out more

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

i have expandable headings that when clicked, show content.

I use a scrollTo method to scroll to the current clicked div to make sure its always in the screen view without the user scrolling.

However, where i currently use fadeIn / Out it looks messy as items are being faded in / out at the same time the page scrolling.

Is there a way i can only fade in / out the content when the scrollTo Has finished? e.g.:

Currently:

```
 $(document).on('click','.headingHelp',function(){
   $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top }, 'slow');
   $('.infoHelp').fadeOut();
   $('.headingHelp_sel').attr('class', 'headingHelp');
   $(this).next('.infoHelp').fadeIn();
   $(this).attr('class', 'headingHelp_sel');
 });
```

However what i want:

```
 function scrollToDiv() {
   $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top }, 'slow');
 }

 $(document).on('click','.headingHelp',function(){
   scrollToDiv() {
     // ONLY DO THIS ONCE FINISHED SCROLLING
     $('.infoHelp').fadeOut();
     $('.headingHelp_sel').attr('class', 'headingHelp');
     $(this).next('.infoHelp').fadeIn();
     $(this).attr('class', 'headingHelp_sel');
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a callback:

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top},'slow',function(){
    //all the code you want to execute later goes here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, you can make use of animate's `promise`:

```
function scrollToDiv() {
    return $('html,body')
               .animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top }, 'slow').promise();
}
```

Use it like this:

```
scrollToDiv().done(function(){
    $('.infoHelp').fadeOut();
    $('.headingHelp_sel').attr('class', 'headingHelp');
    $(this).next('.infoHelp').fadeIn();
    $(this).attr('class', 'headingHelp_sel');
});
```

Comment: Nothing works when using this. No scrolling or anything after that :/